# close popup when clicking outside javascript (not using Jquery)

Tags: javascript, popup

I am a very novice coder and am not sure how to incorporate Jquery. Simply, I am trying to close a popup by clicking outside of it, for clicking the popup image leads to a link. I want to do this in javascript as I have many popups throughout the site. Many thanks for any help.

Here is the HTML:

```
 <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction(this)"><span class="castName">Viola</span>
<span class="popuptext myPopup">      
  <a href="Viola_1.jpg" target="_blank"><img src=Viola_1.jpg style="width:300px;height:auto;" alt="Viola"></a><p>Miss Ellen Terry as Viola, mid to late 19th century</p></span></div>
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
function myFunction(element) {   
var popup = element.getElementsByClassName('myPopup');
 var i;
 for( i=0; i<popup.length; i--) {
 popup[i].classList.toggle('show');
 }
 }
```

Comment: please provide a working jsfiddle.net

Comment: Hi Jared, To tell you the truth I have no idea how to make this work in jsfiddle. I am still working on it in Brackets and do not have a live site